# Error messages about loading DDLs when starting WAMP server

Tags: wampserver

I am receiving these error message when starting WAMP server:

[image: Imgur]

and

[image: Imgur]

How can I fix the problems?

Comment: Useually means you have multiple php versions installed - search for and rename any php.ini files apart from the one in wamp directiry

Comment: If you downloaded 64 bit version try 32... otherwise get the dll online from php. Had to do that with curl once.

Comment: Dont remove any `php.ini` files that live in the `\wamp` file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the message your dll files either are missing or are damaged. Your best bet is to reinstall WampServer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install wamp, but do install first this one 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=30679

In the wamp website it was stated that you must install the vcredist_x64/86.exe

Stated here : http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

As @reignsly said, it looks like you did not download and install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package.

Please make sure you have the latest version of all of these Microsoft C/C++ Redistributable runtime libraries. You dont need the whole compiler, just these C/C++ runtime libraries.

**FOR WAMPServer 32bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 or 2.5 32bit and therefore Apache 2.4.x**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 is required](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x86.exe

**FOR WAMPServer 64bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

```
Yes you need the x86 Package regardless as 
wampmanager is a 32bit exe even on a 64 bit install
```

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 64bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x64.exe

**Warning:** The naming convention used for the redist install files is a bit confusing, so download one, install it, then download the next and install it.... otherwwise you will get confused.

Once they are installed your 'Programs and Features' should look something like this :-

32bit systems
[image: 32bit system]

64bit systems
[image: 64bit system]

The `Unable to load dll issue` is simply fixed by getting WAMPServer to refresh the SYMLINKS in the ...\apache2.4.9\bin folder

Do this as follows using the Wampmanager menus :-

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Version
and click on the version number, probably 2.4.9
```

It takes a couple of second to complete and you wont notice anything going on, but the php_intl error should be solved.